# reference from equation does not work well

Tags: equations, ref, scrartcl

I have a problem with: `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`
it only references the equation number not the chapter and the equation number.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % LAST Package (reference links) 

\numberwithin{equation}{section} 

\begin{document} 
\section{first chapter} 
Fist Equation: 

\begin{equation} 
E=\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon} 
\end{equation}\label{eq:1} 

\section{second chapter} 
Second Equation: 

\begin{equation} 
\varepsilon=\frac{\Delta l}{l_0} 
\end{equation}\label{eq:2} 

The EQ1 in Eq.\ref{eq:1} can be determined with the Equation \ref{eq:2} 

\end{document}
```

Output is:

> The EQ in Eq.1 can be determined with the Equation 2

But I want:

> The EQ in Eq.1.1 can be determined with the Equation 2.1

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I've added the [koma-script] tag because `scrartcl` has its own way of numbering, so this should be looked at by someone familiar with that system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the position of your label

```
\begin{equation} 
  E=\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon} 
  \label{eq:1} 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: nothing against downvotes. But I would be happy as a newcomer to constructive criticism

Comment: I suggest positioning like `\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}`, it is very easy to see in code and also allows for very straightforward searching in the files.